# ffmpeg streaming to rtmp at 30fps

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, rtmp

I am trying to stream my desktop to facebook rtmp server using screen-capture-recorder:

```
 -re  -rtbufsize 256M -f dshow -i audio="Mikrofon (Realtek Audio)" 
-rtbufsize 256M -f dshow -i audio="virtual-audio-capturer"  
-rtbufsize 1024M -f dshow -i video=screen-capture-recorder -r 30  
-filter:v scale=1280:720 -c:v  h264_nvenc -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset fast 
-b:v 8M -maxrate:v 10M  -c:a aac -b:a 128k -ar 44100 
-f flv rtmp://live-api.facebook.com:80/rtmp/..............
```

I am  using h264_nvenc codec for gpu acceleration, but I can stream at only 12-18 fps. However, when I stream into a file:

```
 -re  -rtbufsize 256M -f dshow -i audio="Mikrofon (Realtek Audio)" 
-rtbufsize 256M -f dshow -i audio="virtual-audio-capturer"  
-rtbufsize 1024M -f dshow -i video=screen-capture-recorder -r 30  
-filter:v scale=1280:720 -c:v  h264_nvenc -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset fast 
-b:v 8M -maxrate:v 10M  -c:a aac -b:a 128k -ar 44100 
D:\test.mp4 -y
```

I get 30 fps without problem, even when playing game (eg. Call of duty 6, pretty HW draining). Is it also possible to stream to rtmp at 30 fps with my command configuration? Thank you

If needed, my ffmpeg build config is:

```
ffmpeg version 3.3.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
```

built with gcc 7.1.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib